# Bullet 2d disappear when the game start

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make a 2 d game in unity and when my player shoot the bullets appear in the scene but don't appear in the game. I also don't know how to flip my player to face right when he moves right and face left when he moves left .
[image: This is the bullete inspector]

here is the code for the bullet weapon and the bullet :

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 20f;
    public int damage = 40;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public GameObject impactEffect;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        Enemy enemy = hitInfo.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        }

        Instantiate(impactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PrefabWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

And here is for the player for facing right/left and it doesn't work

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 300;
    public GameObject character;
    private Rigidbody2D characterBody;
    private float ScreenWidth;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Score gm;
    public bool isDead = false;
    public Vector2 jumpHeight;
    public int jumpCount = 0;
    internal static object instance;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.width;
        characterBody = character.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gameMaster").GetComponent<Score>();
        rb2d = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb2d.freezeRotation = true;



    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDead) { return; }
        if (jumpCount < 3 && (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)))  //makes player jump
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumpCount++;
        }
        jumpCount = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < Input.touchCount)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                RunCharacter(1.0f);
                Flip();
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                RunCharacter(-1.0f);
                Flip();
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        RunCharacter(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
#endif 

    }

    private void RunCharacter(float horizontalInput)
    {
        characterBody.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));

    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {
            isDead = true;
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GameController.Instance.Die();
        }
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("coin"))
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            gm.score += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If bullets appear in the scene the they either have wrong order or wrong z position.
  As per [help],[ask],[tour] please only do 1 question per post..

Answer (score 0):

To flip the object, you can change the x scale to negative, or change the value of flipX/flipY of the SpriteRenderer component. To flip the collider and its children together, use the first method.